# new shape and old shape must have the same number of elements

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow.js

For learning purpose, I am using Tensorflow.js, and I experience an error while trying to use the `fit` method with a batched dataset (10 by 10) to learn the process of batch training.

I have got a few images 600x600x3 that I want to classify (2 outputs, either 1 or 0)

Here is my training loop:

```
  const batches = await loadDataset()

  for (let i = 0; i < batches.length; i++) {
    const batch = batches[i]
    const xs = batch.xs.reshape([batch.size, 600, 600, 3])
    const ys = tf.oneHot(batch.ys, 2)

    console.log({
      xs: xs.shape,
      ys: ys.shape,
    })
    // { xs: [ 10, 600, 600, 3 ], ys: [ 10, 2 ] }

    const history = await model.fit(
      xs, ys,
      {
        batchSize: batch.size,
        epochs: 1
      }) // <----- The code throws here

    const loss = history.history.loss[0]
    const accuracy = history.history.acc[0]

    console.log({ loss, accuracy })
  }
```

Here is how I define the dataset

```
const chunks = chunk(examples, BATCH_SIZE)

const batches = chunks.map(
  batch => {
    const ys = tf.tensor1d(batch.map(e => e.y), 'int32')
    const xs = batch
      .map(e => imageToInput(e.x, 3))
      .reduce((p, c) => p ? p.concat(c) : c)
    return { size: batch.length, xs , ys }
  }
)
```

Here is the model:

```
const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [600, 600, 3],
  kernelSize: 60,
  filters: 50,
  strides: 20,
  activation: 'relu',
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}))
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
  poolSize: [20, 20],
  strides: [20, 20]
}))
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  kernelSize: 5,
  filters: 100,
  strides: 20,
  activation: 'relu',
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}))

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
  poolSize: [20, 20],
  strides: [20, 20]
}))
model.add(tf.layers.flatten())
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: 2,
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
  activation: 'softmax'
}))
```

I get an error during the first iteration in the for-loop, from the `.fit` which is the following:

```
Error: new shape and old shape must have the same number of elements.
    at Object.assert (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/util.js:36:15)
    at reshape_ (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:271:10)
    at Object.reshape (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:23:29)
    at Tensor.reshape (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor.js:273:26)
    at Object.derB [as $b] (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/binary_ops.js:32:24)
    at _loop_1 (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tape.js:90:47)
    at Object.backpropagateGradients (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tape.js:108:9)
    at /Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:334:20
    at /Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:91:22
    at Engine.scopedRun (/Users/person/nn/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:101:23)
```

I don't know what to understand from that and found no documentation or help on that specific error, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of the model lies in the way the `convolution` is applied along with the `maxPooling`

The first layer is doing a convolution of kernelSize 60 with a strides of [20, 20] and 50 filters.
The output of this layer will have the approximate shape `[600 / 20, 600 / 20, 50] = [30, 30, 50]`

The max pooling is applied with a stride of `[20, 20]`. The output of this layer will also have the approximate shape `[30 / 20, 30 / 20, 50] =[1, 1, 50 ]`

From this step, the model can no longer perform a convolution with a kernelSize 5.  For the kernel shape `[5, 5]` is bigger than the input shape `[1, 1]` resulting in the error that is thrown. The only convolution the model can perform is that of a kernel whose size is 1. Obviously, that convolution will output the input without any transformation.

The same rule applies to the last `maxPooling` whose `poolingSize` cannot be different from 1, otherwise an error will be thrown.

Here is a snippet:

```js
const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [600, 600, 3],
  kernelSize: 60,
  filters: 50,
  strides: 20,
  activation: 'relu',
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}))
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
  poolSize: [20, 20],
  strides: [20, 20]
}))
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  kernelSize: 1,
  filters: 100,
  strides: 20,
  activation: 'relu',
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}))

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
  poolSize: 1,
  strides: [20, 20]
}))
model.add(tf.layers.flatten())
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: 2,
  kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
  activation: 'softmax'
}))

model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
model.fit(tf.ones([10, 600, 600, 3]), tf.ones([10, 2]), {batchSize: 4});

model.predict(tf.ones([1, 600, 600, 3])).print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```