# TensorflowJs conv2d - Tensor Shapes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I want to create a machine learning model for audio files. I converted the audio files into a (spectrogram) tensor. My feature tensor (the audio files) has the following shape `[119, 241, 125]` (119 files, 241 samples/file, 125 frequencies/sample). By sample, I define the samples I took in a timespan e.g. 16ms. My output shape will be `[119, numOptions]`.

I followed this [tutorial from Tensorflow.js](https://youtu.be/-1QGEQWhmSI?t=655) on audio recognition. They build this model:

[image: Model]

I reshape my features tensor to be 4D: 
`this.features = this.features.reshape([this.features.shape[0],this.features.shape[1],this.features.shape[2],1])`for the 2Dconv.

```
  buildModel() {
        const inputShape1 = [this.features.shape[1], this.features.shape[2],this.features.shape[3]];
        this.model = tfNode.sequential();
        // filter to the image => feature extractor, edge detector, sharpener (depends on the models understanding)
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.conv2d(
            {filters: 8, kernelSize: [4, 2], activation: 'relu', inputShape: inputShape1}
        ));

        // see the image at a higher level, generalize it more, prevent overfit
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.maxPooling2d(
            {poolSize: [2, 2], strides: [2, 2]}
        ));

        // filter to the image => feature extractor, edge detector, sharpener (depends on the models understanding)
        const inputShape2 = [119,62,8];
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.conv2d(
            {filters: 32, kernelSize: [4, 2], activation: 'relu', inputShape: inputShape2}
        ));

        // see the image at a higher level, generalize it more, prevent overfit
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.maxPooling2d(
            {poolSize: [2, 2], strides: [2, 2]}
        ));

        // filter to the image => feature extractor, edge detector, sharpener (depends on the models understanding)
        const inputShape3 = [58,30,32];
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.conv2d(
            {filters: 32, kernelSize: [4, 2], activation: 'relu', inputShape: inputShape3}
        ));

        // see the image at a higher level, generalize it more, prevent overfit
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.maxPooling2d(
            {poolSize: [2, 2], strides: [2, 2]}
        ));

        // 1D output, => final output score of labels
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.flatten({}));

        // prevents overfitting, randomly set 0
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.dropout({rate: 0.25}));

        // learn anything linear, non linear comb. from conv. and soft pool
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.dense({units: 2000, activation: 'relu'}));

        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.dropout({rate: 0.25}));

        // give probability for each label
        this.model.add(tfNode.layers.dense({units: this.labels.shape[1], activation: 'softmax'}));

        this.model.summary();

        // compile the model
        this.model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'adam'});
        this.model.summary()
    };
```

### Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_Conv2D1 (Conv2D)      [null,238,124,8]          72        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_MaxPooling2D1  [null,119,62,8]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_Conv2D2 (Conv2D)      [null,116,61,32]          2080      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_MaxPooling2D2  [null,58,30,32]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_Conv2D3 (Conv2D)      [null,55,29,32]           8224      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_MaxPooling2D3  [null,27,14,32]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_Flatten1 (Flatten)   [null,12096]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_Dropout1 (Dropout)   [null,12096]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,2000]               24194000  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_Dropout2 (Dropout)   [null,2000]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense2 (Dense)         [null,2]                  4002      
=================================================================
Total params: 24208378
Trainable params: 24208378
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
    Epoch 1 / 10
eta=0.0 ======================================>----------------------------------------------------------------------------- loss=0.515 0.51476
eta=0.8 ============================================================================>--------------------------------------- loss=0.442 0.44186
eta=0.0 ===================================================================================================================> 
3449ms 32236us/step - loss=0.485 val_loss=0.958 
Epoch 2 / 10
eta=0.0 ======================================>----------------------------------------------------------------------------- loss=0.422 0.42188
eta=0.9 ============================================================================>--------------------------------------- loss=0.395 0.39535
eta=0.0 ===================================================================================================================> 
3643ms 34043us/step - loss=0.411 val_loss=0.958 
Epoch 3 / 10
```

1) The first input size is my features tensor shape. The other two inputShapes `(inputShape2, inputShape3)` where defined by the error message I got. How to determine the following two input sizes in advance?

Comment: Please what's the error you got ?

Comment: It's more a general question, how I determine the input sizes of the subsequent layers. I make an edit, the 2nd question can be skipped.

Comment: I meant with error msg: initially, I just filled anything into `inputShape2` and `inputShape3`. Then I got an error, and from that error, I took the shapes. But I was wondering how this is calculated.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How the inputShape is calculated ?**

It is not the inputShape that is calculated. It is the dataset that is passed to the model that has to match the `inputShape`. While defining the model, the inputShape is of 3D. But looking at the model summary, there is a fourth dimension with value `null` that is the batchshape. As a result, the training data should be of 4D. The first dimension or batchshape can be whatever - what matters is for the features and the labels to have the same batchshape. There is a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737522/tensorflow-js-inputshape-doesnt-match-model-input)

**How the layers shape is calculated ?**

It depends of the layers used. Layers such as `dropout`, `activation` don't change the input shape.

- Depending on the stride kernel, the convolution layer will change the input shape. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729443/new-shape-and-old-shape-must-have-the-same-number-of-elements) details how it is calculated.
- A flatten layer will simply reshape the inputShape to be of one dimension. In the model summary, there is the input shape `[null,27,14,32]` and the flatten layer has the shape `[null, 12096] (12096 = 27 * 14 *32)`
- The dense layer will also change the input shape. The shape of the dense layer depends of the number of units of that layer.